# clang-format: How to prevent space before {}?

Tags: c++11, clang-format

I'd like to make `auto foo = Foo {};` become `auto foo = Foo{};`.

What would be the correct property?

My style works when applied from CLI, but this is the only thing that Qt Creator ruins when I save my edited file.

Comment: Can you update your question with some of the properties you have tried that don't work?

Answer (score 1):

The property seemed to be `SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true`, but unfortunately it's not supported by `clang-format-6.0` I still have to use.